# Как запустить две асинхронные функции параллельно?

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет,у меня есть две функции,одна из них бесконечно работает за счет while true ,вторая функция команды бота,естественно вторая команда не работает,пока выполняется бесконечная,как сделать многопоточность?

```
async def take_id(message: types.Message): и async def foo():
while True:
for nick in users_nick:
await asyncio.create_task(lot())
asyncio.run(foo())
```

Comment: А разве нет никакого метода чтобы хендлить событие? Просто через `while True` не слишком хорошая идея проверять, оптимизация будет хромать.

Comment: К сожалению не нашёл